# How to remove redundant zeros from expression?

Tags: matrix

I have the following code:

```
In[94]:= MM = Table[RandomReal[{-1, 1}], {2}, {2}]

Out[94]= {{-0.652836, -0.601151}, {-0.772436, 0.795763}}

In[95]:= MM = MM * x

Out[95]= {{-0.652836 x, -0.601151 x}, {-0.772436 x, 0.795763 x}}

In[98]:= MM . IdentityMatrix[2]

Out[98]= {{0. - 0.652836 x, 0. - 0.601151 x}, {0. - 0.772436 x, 
0. + 0.795763 x}}
```

A trivial imaginary part is added to the matrix product where all variables are essentially real numbers. Is there a way to remove these "0."s because they're going to make following computation look messy ?

Comment: I see no imaginary part in the complex number sense (`Re` or `Chop` are common ways to get rid of `0. I`).  I see a floating-point `Real` zero, `0.`.  *Mathematica* does not get rid of it automatically, because sometimes there are reasons to keep it.  However, `expr /. 0. -> 0` changes them to an exact `0`, which will disappear, unless it's the only term in the expression.

Comment: I edited the title because there is no imaginary unit in the expression.

Answer (score 9):

The `0.` does not disappear from an expression such as `0. + 1.5 x` because it is an inexact zero. Anything in Mathematica containing a decimal point is considered "inexact", meaning that it is interpreted as "known only up to a certain number of digits", thus potentially not precisely zero.

See here for details: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Numbers.html

The typical way to remove very small numbers which you consider to be close enough to zero to be ignorable is [`Chop`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Chop.html). It will replace small numbers with `0` (i.e. an *exact* zero). Be sure to read about tolerances under the "Details" section of `Chop`'s documentation page.

```
In[1]:= Chop[0. + 1.5 x]
Out[1]= 1.5 x
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a commentary than an answer, since I am currently - and, perhaps, never will be - permitted to write comments.

I recently ran into a similar annoying problem in the context of computing stages in the development of biological tissues. There, one small aspect is the canonical "toggle" between the resting and activated states of a cell. The Toggle computes to a graph (see attached image) whose states can be determined via

[image: HSGraphStates gives the states of the Laplacian of a graph]

The state matrix is

[image: State matrix of toggle graph.]

It is easy to see that

[image: The product of the state matrix with itself times I]

is the second Pauli matrix

PauliMatrix@2

However, annoyingly, the product gives

{{0. + 0. I, 0. - 1. I}, {0. + 1. I, 0. + 0. I}}

which gives

In[276]:= % === PauliMatrix@2

Out[276]= False

Using Chop gives:

In[232]:= Chop@%%

Out[232]= {{0, 0. - 1. I}, {0. + 1. I, 0}}

which also gives False.

On the other hand, using Round gives:

In[275]:= Round@{{0. `+ 0.` I,
0. `- 0.9999999999999998` I}, {0. `+ 0.9999999999999998` I,
0. `+ 0.` I}}

Out[275]= {{0, -I}, {I, 0}}

so that

In[274]:= % === PauliMatrix@2

Out[274]= True

It is, perhaps, a drawback that the above commentary is not entirely on target as an answer for the rephrased question. Yet, I felt that similar questions concerning complex arithmetic have popped up over time such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8780068/mathematica-finding-the-conditions-for-the-real-part-of-a-complex-number-to-be) or [here](https://groups.google.com/g/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/c/QB3QYAqpbN4). Moreover, the documentation for Chop states "Consequently, Chop does not make the real part of machine complex numbers an exact zero:" and indeed

In[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0V9MW.png):= Chop[0. + 2. I]

Out[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0V9MW.png)= 0. + 2. I

while Round gives

In[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5BJT.png):= Round[0. + 2. I]

Out[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5BJT.png)= 2 I

Another drawback, of course, is this pesky little detail :)

In[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHebW.png):= Round[0. + 2.1 I]

Out[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHebW.png)= 2 I

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/115054)

Comment: Thank you. I agree. I was aware of this issue and apologized for it in advance in the text.

Comment: @Dunlop: On the other hand it seems to me that the substitution `MM*x/.(x->I)` generates the same problem for complex numbers as asked in the original question.